# The method 'openAudioSession' isn't defined for the type 'FlutterSoundRecorder'

Tags: flutter, voice-recording

I am writing a flutter app for recording voice using flutter_sound package

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"
```

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_sound: ^9.1.2
  permission_handler: ^8.3.0
```

```
import 'package:flutter_sound/flutter_sound.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

```
Future init() async {
    _audioRecorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();

    final status = await Permission.microphone.request();
    if (status != PermissionStatus.granted){
      throw RecordingPermissionException('Microphone permission denied.');
    }
    await _audioRecorder!.openAudioSession();
    _isRecorderInitiated = true;
 }
```

I am getting this error

```
The method 'openAudioSession' isn't defined for the type 'FlutterSoundRecorder'.
```

Can anybody help me in finding out what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems to have been [removed](https://github.com/Canardoux/flutter_sound/commit/342e0f0ec3314a80071d33df3b327e3f1516ccfa) in version 9, but the documentation has not been updated. You can use `openRecorder()` instead or switch to an older version of the library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems you'r right. I replaced openAudioSession() with openRecorder() and closeAudioSession() with closeRecorder(). It works. There may be more changes in flutter_sound package. Can you suggest me how can I learn about flutter_sound more.